# Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Timer.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, .net-4.5.2

While trying to build a Visual Studio 2013 C# solution with MSBuild, the following error is displayed and the build is aborted.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): e
rror MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\
Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
.2\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module w
as expected to contain an assembly manifest.'  [*.csproj]
```

I've tried updating and reinstalling .NET v4.5.2, but it hasn't helped.

What's strange is that renaming System.Threading.Timer.dll makes the project buildable, but then other parts of the solution complain that it's missing.

Comment: I think you may be experiencing a name clash. Do you have a DLL or project with the same name?

Comment: Also, what Framework version are you building for?

Comment: @Juan No, can't find anything with the same name. I'm building for v4.5.2

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all projects are building for that version? Also, x86 or x64?

Comment: @Juan Yes, all projects are for 4.5.2, even when trying to build just this project the error occurs. Platform target: Any CPU.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? Also, try setting the reference to copy local and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I've tried cleaning the solution. Can't add a reference to the .dll because of--it causes an error `A reference to ... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`. Also, it's already listed as a nuget dependency.

Comment: Oh I see. A few things to check. Make sure you at least have Nuget 3.4 as it's listed as a requirement. Uninstall the package and install it again. Try building for 4.5.1 and see what happens. Let me know!

Comment: I'll try that (NuGet version = 2.12). Building for 4.5.1 (or 4.5) doesn't give the `System.Threading.Timer.dll` error but the project is dependent upon 4.5.2 so other things break.

Comment: NuGet 2.12 is the last version for VS2013.

Comment: It looks like that might be your issue right there. Try installing the package manually as opposed to using Nuget.

Comment: It looks like downloading the package via the latest NuGet and replacing the (corrupted, I guess) .dll in Program Files worked. Thanks @Juan !

Comment: Awesome. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your project file where the assemblies are referenced might be corrupted. Try this.

1. Clear the `\bin` folder of your project
2. Clear the temp folder in `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: Do you have the nuget package which downloads the dll installed in your project? `Install-Package System.Threading.Timer`

Comment: No, but the .dll is already in `C:\
Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\System.Threading.Timer.dll`. Will try to add the nuget package.

Comment: Can you post what you have in your app.config so we can see what dependencies are being referenced.

Comment: I added the System.Threading.Timer via nuget. The error persists.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

Clear your bin directory and then Clean and Build the solution If you still get the same error then Go to your reference folder and remove the delete manually and add again it might not be compatible